# How do I remove a certain RGB Value from a image?

Tags: java

I have been stuck for a while with this issue. My idea or what I'd like to be able to do is take a BufferedImage and check to see if the BufferedImage contains a certain RGB value. If it has given RGB Value, then I want to remove that color completely from the image and making it transparent.

Here is my idea in code:

```
public static BufferedImage grabSubImage(BufferedImage image) { 
    Color backgroundToRemove = new Color(253, 28, 253);
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight(); 

    for (int imageWidth = 0; imageWidth < width; imageWidth++) { 
         for (int imageHeight = 0; imageHeight < height; imageHeight++) {
              int pixel = image.getRBG(imageWidth, imageHeight); 
              if (pixel == backgroundToRemove) image.removeBackgroundColor(); //Not an Actual Method           
         }
   }
   return image; 
}
```

Here is my image: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/faEk1.png

The image in question is in: (4, 0) or since each box is 16 width px (16 * 4, 0)

Thanks for your help in advance! It's much appreciated!

Comment: What's your actual question? You seem to have a good setup.

Comment: Do not put the return in the loop. Just use one return at the end so you prevent any possible `NullPointerException` if you want to use the image again. Apart from that the method looks solid. Maybe add the possibility to  pass the color you want to remove as an argument, so you can remove different backgrounds with one method.

Comment: @JohannisK yeah it makes sense, but there isn't a method that will allow you to remove a background and I don't know how you can make said method. Additionally, you can't compare an int value with a color. So that's wrong too.

Comment: Just set the color to a transparent white (ARGB 0,0,0,0) since PNG and Java both allow transparency values so the pixel becomes invisible. There should be a method called `Image.setRGB()` or similar.

Comment: @GiantTree Okay that helps, however, the thing I am missing is how exactly you can check if said Color is contained inside the BufferedImage obj? Once that's check is complete you can do what you are acknowledging.

Comment: You are already doing it by iterating over each pixel to check if the values match. If you want to use something like a subtract filter then you should look into image filters in `java.awt.image`.